# How to make my PWA start fullscreen (via Android Google PWA)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My manifest sets the display to fullscreen

```
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "fullscreen"
```

but I only get the "standalone" behavior. Android's bottom navigation bar is still visible. Why is that? Using Android 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting `display` is not enough. The `start_url` also needs a `fullscreen` parameter.

```
  "start_url": "index.html?fullscreen=true",
  "display": "fullscreen"
```